# Database table creation dates 'self changed'

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel, plesk, auto-update

I noticed today that a MySQL database I was working on had table creation dates only two days ago. They were actually created years earlier.

It quickly became apparent that the very recent creation date also matches down to the mili-second creation times for many tables across multiple databases on our server. Searching for what had taken place on the server at that specific time, I found that Plesk updated itself at that precise time.

If you're not familiar with it, Plesk is similar to cPanel. It helps manage everything from domain setup, down to creating databases. In that sense, it has rights to much of the server resources.

Is it typical that updating Plesk / cPanel, or other hosting management consoles with access to create databases resets table creation dates? Or, was this a poorly implemented Plesk update, and I should normally be able to trust the table creation date?

Comment: Some programs which uses a database alters database structure during version updates. Some of these sructure alterings cannot be performed online, and hence they use COPY algorythm. During this process server creates new table body file, copies the data into new structure, deletes old body file and renames new one. Of course datetime of the file creation become equal to updating process timestamp.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with "table create dates"? MySQL does not track this at all. Are you referring to the file system creation time info for the actual table files?